# cdk drag of component that has content

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have a component of circle. In this circle there is a div of data .When I am starting to drag the whole component with its content inside, the circle is duplicated without the div with the data inside.
The hierarchy is as following:

```
<circle-component cdkDrag cdkDropList> // the circle is dragable
   <div> // when drag is started the circle is duplicated without the data inside 
        some data here
   </div
</circle-component>
```

maybe I need to copy the circle component in some way.. What should I try in order to see the circle and the content of it when drag is started ? 
** the data is passed as @Input to the circle component

Answer (score 0):

ckdDrag is the "draggable" object, cdkDropList is a collection (can be an unique element) that has "inside" dragables objects.

So, if you only want to drag the circle

```
<circle-component cdkDrag > // remove the cdkList
   <div> 
        some data here
   </div
</circle-component>
```

If you has control some kind of data

```
   <div cdkList>
      <circle-component cdkDrag > // the cdkDrag "inside" a cdkList
         <div> 
             some data here
        </div
      </circle-component>
   </div>
```

Comment: If I remove the dropList i can move the circle, but the circle is not overlapping others..